# WebForms ConnectionStrings does not work well and generated database name is different

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, webforms

I am new to web forms. I am following the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/ui_and_navigation#reviewing-the-database) to create the project in vs 2019.

When I seed data according to the tutorial, I have errors since the database is not generated successfully:

```
public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public ProductContext() : base("WingtipToys")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products{ get;set; }
}
```

Web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WingtipToys-20131119102907.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WingtipToys-20131119102907;Integrated Security=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="WingtipToys"
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\wingtiptoys.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

But when I use the default connection string instead of `WingtipToys`, it generates the database successfully.

```
public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public ProductContext() : base()//use default connection
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products{ get;set; }
}
```

But the generated database is named `WingtipToys.Models.ProductContext`, shouldn't it be what I set in connectionString?

So,my questions are why this happen and how can I connect to the `WingtipToys` connectionString...

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you wanting to learn WebForms? WebForms has been obsolete since 2008 when ASP.NET MVC was released.

Comment: @Dai I just want to know something about it.I have learnt MVC and want to try some WebForms projects